# Passing second argument onwards from a shell script to Java

Tags: bash

If I pass any number of arguments to a shell script that invokes a Java program internally, how can I pass second argument onwards to the Java program except the first?

./my_script.sh a b c d ....

```
#my_script.sh
...
java MyApp b c d ...
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057815/how-to-get-second-to-last-argument-from-previous-bash-command

Answer (score 78):

First use `shift` to "consume" the first argument, then pass `"$@"`, i.e., the list of remaining arguments:

```
#my_script.sh
...
shift
java MyApp "$@"
```

Comment: The special parameter `@` should "always" be quoted: `"$@"`, otherwise is not different from `$*`. Also, should be mentioned that after the `shift`, if not previously saved, the first parameter is lost.

Comment: @enzotib Thanks, I've quoted `$@`.

Comment: Doesn't quoting it cause all the arguments to be passed as a single argument, a list of space-separated arguments? I assume not, given the popularity of this answer, but maybe you can explain.

Comment: @nilbus: $@ is a special parameter, and behaves differently from other variables. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html.

Answer (score 49):

You can pass second argument onwards without using "shift" as well.

```
set -- 1 2 3 4 5

echo "${@:0}"
echo "${@:1}"
echo "${@:2}"   # here
```

Comment: does not work in `sh`, only `bash`. this is called substring expansion and has a special behaviour for `@`. usually it counts the characters, but for `@` it counts the parameters.

Comment: I see it defined as "Substring Extraction" here: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html. `Substring Extraction

${string:position}

    Extracts substring from $string at $position.

    If the $string parameter is "*" or "@", then this extracts the positional parameters, [1] starting at $position.`