# Git alias for rebase to common ancestor

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to make a git alias to rebase onto the common ancestor of another branch. So that I can type...

```
git rbca develop -i
```

and it gets expanded to...

```
git rebase $(git merge-base HEAD develop) -i
```

Here is what I have:

```
rbca = "!git rebase $(git merge-base HEAD $1) #"
```

I'm very close. They only problem is that the `#` doesn't work as expected so the `-i` has no effect.

Here are the other SO answers that have gotten me this far.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4207357/2019549
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39523506/2019549

Comment: The second question you linked to says "The final # is important - it prevents all the user-supplied arguments from being processed by the shell (it comments them out)". So.. it sounds like you want to leave off the final `#`?

Comment: @omajid That doesn't work. It seems like the develop argument is double counted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I need to add arguments 2 and after using `${@:2}` and still use `#` to prevent arguments from being added again.

```
rbca = "!git rebase $(git merge-base HEAD \"$1\") ${@:2} #"
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3995365/2019549